# Norm inequality for complex matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, normed-spaces

> Prove that there exist a constant $C>0$ such that for all matrices
>   $A\in\mathbb{C}^{3\times3}$, there exists $P\in U(3)$ and a diagonal
>   $D\in\mathbb{C}^{3\times3}$ such that $$||P^*AP - D||^2\leq
>  C||A^*A-AA^*||,$$ where $||B||=\sqrt{\mbox{tr}(BB^*)}$ denotes the
>   Hilbert-Schmidt norm of $B$.
>
> Hint: Prove the statement for the class of triangular matrices first.

Unfortunately I wasn't able to prove it even in case if $A$ is triangular. I wrote how $3\times3$ triangular matrix would look like and then tried to calculate explicitly $A^*A-AA^*$, but it doesn't look like a correct path to the solution. I also don't know how to generalize the result from the triangular case to arbitrary matrix. Are triangular matrices dense in the space of all complex matrices?

I will be grateful if someone will be able to explain the solution to this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: A potentially helpful observation:
$$
\|AA^* - A^*A\|^2 = \operatorname{tr}([AA^* - A^*A]^2) 
\\ = \operatorname{tr}(AA^*AA^* - AA^*A^*A - A^*AAA^* + A^*AA^*A)
\\ = 2\operatorname{tr}((A^*A)^2) - 2\operatorname{tr}(A^2(A^2)^*)
\\ = 2(\|A^*A\|^2 - \|A^2\|^2)
$$

Comment: As for extending the result: it suffices to note that every matrix [can be unitarily upper-triangularized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_decomposition)

Comment: I suspect that if $A$ is triangular, then it suffices to take $P = I$

Comment: If my suspicion is right, then the triangular case amounts to proving that 
$$
\frac{|a_{12}|^2 + |a_{23}|^2 + |a_{31}|^2}{\|AA^* - A^*A\|}
$$
has a finite upper-bound